# How to insert a Whole LinearLayout in the same Activity on a Button click in android Programming?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

this is my xml code and i want to insert the whole LinearLayout id(l1) as i click the Mainbutton defined with id(b1). Thing to note is that the  linearLayout l1 also contains a textview and a Button.
I know how to insert a View on a button click but i can't find how to insert a Whole Layout on a button Click.
Hope there is no need for .java file. please Define your own onClick method for doing so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.akash.courtcounter.MainActivity"
    android:background="#e5e2e2">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main Button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#c5ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView Here"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:textColor="#747070"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:background="#d3d6d8"
            android:onClick="increase"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here but a `LinearLayout` extends from `View` so anything you can do with `View` you can do with `LinearLayout`. But if you are just trying to make `LinearLayout` and its contents visible then just make the `LinearLayout` visible. You already have it in your `xml` `layout` file.

Comment: i just want to insert a new layout vertically with format of layout l1 next to each other not just hide and unhide the same layout

Answer (score 1):

You should inflate a new layout dynamically and add it to your parent Linear Layout

`LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
View newLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_layout, null, false);
myLayout.addView(newLayout);`

new_layout is your layout what you want to add dynamically.

Comment: in second line .inflate(R.layout.new_layout, null, false); only allowing me to insert my xml file name i.e activity_main in place of new_layout and not the layout reference i want to create dynamically

Comment: @akash, there are two layouts "main_layout" where your parent layout lies and another layout is "new_layout", which you can inflate and add to parent layout dynamically.

Comment: but it is not giving me any suggestion for entering any layout only suggestion is for activity_main

Comment: you need to create a new layout apart from your main layout i.e. "new_layout"

Answer (score 0):

By default make LinearLayout invisible from your .xml file

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#c5ffffff"
       android:id="@+id/l1"
       android:visibility="gone"                         //it hides the entire linear layout
       android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     //Add your views here
      <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />




    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     //Add your views here
      <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />




    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     //Add your views here
      <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />




    </LinearLayout>
```

then in your .java file

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout l1;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 l1 = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.l1);

 l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


             l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          //on button click Linear Layout will be visible


         }
      });
}
```

}

Comment: thanks but i want to insert multiple l1 layouts next to each other vertically

Comment: do you want to insert same layout multiple times?

Comment: i want to insert and create the new layout dynamically , just at the  time i clicked the button

Comment: instead of creating dynamically, its better to define the layout in xml and make it invisible, and on button click just make it visible

Comment: what if someone need more layouts than i actually defined?